# .htaccess working "sometimes" and doesn't like relative links

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am working on a project right now, after other projects some weeks ago using also .htaccess redirection without any problem.
I am using last version of WAMP and this time .htaccess drives me crazy.
No RewriteBase.

Apache modules are activated for redirection and all should work, example with :

```
RewriteRule ^test$ trying.php [L]
```

and trying.php is like :

```
<?php
echo "lol";
?>
```

I have :

[ex1 http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/180473es1.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/180473es1.png)

So right, it should work ! I then try to access a member page but this member **doesn't exist** so there only should be the title of the page in the header, my .htaccess is like :

```
RewriteRule ^member/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ member.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and I obtain :

[ex2 http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/336923es2.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/336923es2.png)

So I have the page without information on the user (as expected) except the title but it doesn't find the css file (relative link to it in the header), not good.

Then I try the real thing, accessing an existing member at this address `http://localhost/try/member/member1` and I am redirected to...

[ex3 http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/480421es3.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/480421es3.png)

It is a [L] redirection not a [R], so why is that happening ? Why does it happen only with existing members ? I restarted WAMP services each time, no explanation.

Comment: You probably noticed, but in your first two images, you're going to `http://localhost/try/<file>` but in the last you're just going straight to the file: `http://localhost/member.php`.  Does it make a difference if you go to `http://localhost/try/member.php` instead?

Comment: In my wamp folder I have subfolders, this project is called "try" and all the files (as member.php) I want to reach are in this folder. For the last image I entered an address with "try/member/member-id" and I ended up at localhost/member.php... :s
When I force the browser to go to "try/member.php?id=member-id", it works well ! With css & co.

Comment: Do you have this in your `.htaccess` file? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` (above the rewrite rule)

Comment: no I don't have any Cond. When adding this one before, with a non existing member it says `Not Found : The requested URL /try/member/sdqdf was not found on this server.` but with an existing it do exactly like before, `Not Found : The requested URL /member.php was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have correct `RewriteBase`. Inside your `/try/.htaccess` have it like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /try/

RewriteRule ^test$ trying.php [L]

RewriteRule ^member/([A-Z0-9]+)/?$ member.php?id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't change anything... Is it possible that Wamp has some bugs ? And do you know how to fix the thing about relative links ?

Comment: Test in a new browser and do post full `/try/.htaccess`

Comment: Wow ! It changed in the new browser ! Now it works ! How could it happen ? There were no cache...

Comment: browser caching is done based on web server's HTTP code